# Does new FileInputStream(templateFile); invoke close() after initialization?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Does constructor `new FileInputStream(someFile);` invoke `close()` method after initialization? Need I call `close()` on this object after it initialization ?

Comment: There wouldn't be much point to it if it did. How would you call all the other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you forget to do this, the file will ordinarily be closed automatically when the program terminates or when the file stream object is garbage collected, but it's best to close a file as soon as you are done with it.

```
File file = new File("DevFile.txt"); // This will create file object with meta info

int ch;
StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
FileInputStream fin = null;

try {
fin = new FileInputStream(file); // It'll open a stream and type is input

while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)// and you can read data stream unless it is closed
strContent.append((char) ch);

fin.close(); // you should close stream to provide safety of your file 

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} catch (IOException ioe) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it just opens the stream; it's up to you to decide when to close it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `close()` method is not called by the constructor, so you should call it when you're done using a particular FileInputStream instance.